# How to override primeng styles?

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, primeng

I need to use PrimeNG in my project. I want to style [Panel Menu](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu).

I need to change border color and background.

HTML:

```
<img class="logo" src="../../../assets/images/MenuLogo.png">
<p-panelMenu [model]="items"></p-panelMenu>
```

SCSS:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu
    {
        width: 250px;
        border: 0px;
        .ui-panelmenu-header
        {
            border: none;
        }
    }
} 
.logo
{
    width: 250px;
}
.test
{
    border: 0px solid black;
}
```

I want to disappear border and background at first, if I using your code like this:

HTTP:

```
<img class="logo" src="../../../assets/images/MenuLogo.png">
<p-panelMenu [style]="{'border':'none', 'background-color':'none'}" [model]="items"></p-panelMenu>
```

I have this:
[image]

But want this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu
    {
        width: 250px;
        border: 0px;
    }
    ::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu-header > a {
        border: none!important;
        background-color: transparent!important;
    }
} 
.logo
{
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

HTML:

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>
```

CSS (of the view):

```css
:host>>>.ui-state-default {
    background: #246bc2!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
}

:host>>>.ui-menuitem-text {
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
}

:host>>>.ui-menuitem-icon {
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
}

:host>>>.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-content .ui-menuitem-text {
    color: #003883!important;
}

:host>>>.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-content .ui-menuitem-icon {
    color: #003883!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this style in global style.css file -

```
body .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header > a {
   border: 0px solid black;
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to edit global style.css file in nude_modules.

Comment: NO, I'm not talking about node_modules one

Comment: In my slide-menu.component.scss that part of code don't affect anything, this file it's not even visible when im debugging my code

Answer (score 0):

In this case use the next code snippet:

```
body .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header > a {
    border: none!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

**Add the code in the css file of the view or in the global style.css/style.scss of the application.**

Comment: After add this code to slide-menu.component.scss i didn't saw any effect.

Comment: That's in strange, delete the 'body' to the css rule.

Answer (score 0):

you can override it in global stylesheet ie `style.scss`
by wrapping the elements with a custom class
this will provide more specificity

```
.your-class {
  .ui-panelmenu {
    .ui-panelmenu-heade {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```